# Limit and Ratio test

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Here the problem 2.3.29(5) from Sohrab, Basic Real Analysis

### Problem

Investigate the convergence or divergence of the following series
$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{3^3}+\cdots$

Hint: note that the Ratio Test is inconclusive.

### Solution

$x_k=\frac{1}{2^k}+\frac{1}{3^k}$. Ratio test:

$$
\lim(x_{n+1}/x_n)=\lim\frac{\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}+\frac{1}{3^{k+1}}}{\frac{1}{2^k}+\frac{1}{3^k}}=\lim
\frac{1}{6}\frac{3^{k+1}+2^{k+1}}{3^k+2^k}\\
=\lim\frac{1}{6}\frac{1+(\frac{2}{3})^{k+1}}{\frac{1}{3}(1+(\frac{2}{3})^k)}=\frac{1}{2}<1.
$$

Thus $\sum(\frac{1}{2^k}+\frac{1}{3^k})$ is convergent.

### Question

Is it possible that the hint is wrong? Otherwise, what is my error?

Comment: The hint is wrong, because by the ratio test, the series converges.

Comment: I expect the hint, such as it was, assumed that the terms were $a_{2n}=3^{-n}$ and $a_{2n-1}=2^{-n}$.  In that case the ratio $\frac {a_{k+1}}{a_k}$ depends on the parity on $k$.  Your method involves rearranging the series (adding first in pairs) which is not justifiable for a general series.  Here it is easy enough to evaluate the partial sums explicitly, so there is no problem.

Comment: @JanEerland Some of those ratios $\to \infty$

Comment: This example is also in Rudin PMA, Example 3.35(a). Rudin also concluded that the ratio test fails, without noticing that, taking two addends together, the ratio test succeeds.

Comment: Yes, but that's the ratio test for a different series.

Comment: Yes, a different series if $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{3^3}+\cdots$ is another series than $(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3})+(\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2})+(\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{3^3})+\cdots$. They are two different maps $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$, but the same sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to write the given expression precisely as an infinite series. I think the problem-writer's thinking was to write it as $\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k$ where
$$
x_k = \begin{cases}
\frac1{2^{(k+1)/2}}\,, &\text{if $k$ is odd}, \\
\frac1{3^{k/2}}, &\text{if $k$ is even}.
\end{cases}
$$
In this form, the Ratio Test is indeed inconclusive. However, if you rewrite it in the form you gave, than the Ratio Test is fine. Since all the terms are positive, you could also just separate the powers of $\frac12$ from the powers of $\frac13$ (into two infinite series) and evaluate each one individually.